# munmap performance on Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, mmap

I have a multi-threaded application on RHEL 5.8 which reads large files (about 500MB each) via mmap and do some processing on them; one thread does the mmap and other threads do the processing.  When the file is no longer on filesystem, munmap is performed to free the memory.
My problem is that munmap (and sometimes close on the file) slows down the other threads, performing operations on a different memory, so I am wondering if there is a better way to implement this.  I have 2 ideas: split the memory to smaller chunks to munmap smaller blocks (is this even possible?), or not use munmap at all and allocate / deallocate memory myself, optionally cache the memory blocks if the file is no longer on filesystem, and reuse it for next file.
Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Twiddling with thread priorities may help.

Comment: Actually, the worker threads use SCHED_RR with priority 50, so they should be prioritized.

Comment: Do you write on the mmapped memory in order to modify the files?

Comment: Could you be more precise about _When the file is no longer on filesystem_ and your `mmap()` parameters (shared/private, protection)

Comment: @ydroneaud Sure.  When I find a file to process on filesystem, I do mmap() (actually the file is on tmpfs filesystem, don't know if it makes a difference); prot is PROT_READ, flags is MAP_SHARED | MAP_POPULATE; although I could probably use MAP_PRIVATE as well.  I only need to read the file.  When the file is removed from filesystem by other process, and my application is done processing it, I call munmap() and close() on the appropriate fd.

Comment: @mehturt so the filesystem have to wait for the file to be unmmaped and closed to actually flushing pages from memory and remove it from disk. Is it possible for your application to unlink() the file *after* closing it / unmapping it ?

Comment: @ydroneaud No, the file is no longer present on filesystem when I call munmap(), so I don't have to call unlink(), right?  Btw. I am measuring duration of munmap() and close() seprately and I see sometimes munmap and sometimes close affects the other threads.

Answer (score 3):

The actual reason it gets slow is that `munmap()` takes the mm->mmap_sem lock for the entire duration of the syscall. Several other operations are liable to be blocked by this, for example (but not limited to) `fork()`/`mmap()`. This is especially important to note for architectures that do not implement a lockless `get_user_pages_fast()` operation for pages already in-memory, because a bunch of futex operations (that underpin pthread primitives) will call `get_user_pages_fast()` and the default implementation will try to take a read lock on `mmap_sem`.

Comment: Thanks. Which architectures that might be (that do not implement a lockless get_user_pages_fast() operation for pages already in-memory)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading the memory sequentially, try to regularly use `posix_madvise()` with `MADV_DONTNEED` on the read memory pages. See [posix_madvise()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_madvise.html).

It's also available as `madvise()` under Linux. See [madvise()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/madvise.2.html)

Comment: The worker threads can access the memory randomly, so I can't do that.  I could do madvise() with MADV_DONTNEED prior to munmap(), but I think it does not make sense, does it?  Or should I try to call madvise() multiple times on parts of the memory region prior to munmap()?

Comment: @mehturt there's no need to call `madvise(MADV_DONTNEED)` just before calling `munmap()`, in this case, it's implicit.

Answer (score 0):

> When the file is no longer on filesystem, munmap is performed

So you call `munmap` when the file is unlinked from the filesystem. Then, probably, what is slowing down the system is the actual deletion of the inode, that is done when all the directory entries, file descriptors and memory maps are released.

There is known issues with the performance of deletes in some filesystems in linux (ext3). If that is the case you could try changing to ext4 (with extents), if that is feasible in your scenario.

Other option would be to hard link the files in other directory, so they are not really deleted when you `munmmap` them. Then, you could call `ionice -c 3 rm <last-link>` or similar to actually delete them in the background...

Comment: The files are stored on tmpfs filesystem.  The file is actually deleted by other process, my process only does munmap() and close() on the underlying file descriptor.

Comment: The other process does the unlink, but it is this very process the one that does the actual deletion of the inoce, as it the one that frees the last reference to it. You could try creating some of these files manually and deleting them using `time rm` to see how much time it takes.

Comment: Yes, my question is whether it is possible to do this so that other threads are not affected.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing (and it proved sufficient) was to munmap the big memory block in pieces, e.g. I had 500MB block and I performed munmap in 100MB chunks.